# Jersey URL invalid encrypt

Tags: java, jax-rs

I use Jersey `javax.ws.rs` to invoque an url

***java:***

```
...
String eoEndPoint = "http://exemple.com/";
String url = "offres/test/2015-01-07?return=2015-01-09&withThac=false";
ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig).register(new Authenticator(user, password));
WebTarget webTarget;
webTarget = client.target(eoEndPoint)
  .path(url);
Invocation.Builder invocationBuider = webTarget.request();
invocationBuider.accept(mediaType);
Offers response = invocationBuider.get(Offers.class);
return response;
...
```

When i execute this code i have an `HTTP 404 Not Found`
why `invocationBuider.get(Offers.class);` transform my url `http://exemple.com/offres/test/2015-01-07?return=2015-01-09&withThac=false` to `http://exemple.com/offres/test/2015-01-07%3Dreturn=2015-01-09&withThac=false`

The `?` is transform to `%3D` why .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing query parameters to the `path()` method that expects an URI  therefore any special characters (e.g. `?`, `=`) are getting escaped. You need to use a dedicated method `queryParam()` to provide query parameters.

Replace

```
.path(url); // "offres/test/2015-01-07?return=2015-01-09&withThac=false";
```

with

```
.path("offres/test/2015-01-07")
.queryParam("return", "2015-01-09")
.queryParam("withThac", "false")
```